# ORACLE SQL REPEAT SAME QUERY

Tags: oracle, plsql

It seems that I haven't been clear enough.
The query that seems to work is:

```
Select ((Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=2 and table1.name=5) as ‘name5’,
(Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=2 and table1.name=7) as ‘name7’)
From table.1;
union
Select ((Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=5 and table1.name=5) as ‘name5’,
(Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=5 and table1.name=7) as ‘name7’)

From table.1;
union
Select ((Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=15 and table1.name=5) as ‘name5’,
(Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=15 and table1.name=7) as ‘name7’)
From table.1;
```

….

Which gets an  outcome like this:

```
name5  name7
    52         47
    42         84
    61         11
```

My problem is that the table1.code has a thousand and more values other than 2,5 and 15 and I can not repeat a union statement for so many times.

Comment: The above given query is not a valid one. Also, please try explaining your problem again. Why do you want to repeat the sql with different value for the same purpose? You can just directly do a `code in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... )` or make `code between 1 and 100`

Comment: How do you define which table1.codes you want?  you could use key words `in`, or `exists` or perform a join on table1 to limit the results.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to reproduce the [N+1 problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you actually just want to group by the values in the code column, and you can use IN or EXISTS

```
select count(table1.id) as theCount, table1.code as theCode
 from table1 where table1.code in ('code a','code b', 'etc...')
group by table1.code;
```

the output would be

```
theCount||theCode
code a || 8074
code b || 34
etc... || 9575
```

or something like that but with non notional numbers for counts
HTH

Comment: The query that seems to work is:
Select (Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=2 and table1.name=5) as ‘name5’,
(Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=2 and table1.name=7) as ‘name7’)
From table.1;
union
Select (Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=5 and table1.name=5) as ‘name5’,
(Select count (table1.id) from table1  where table1.code=5 and table1.name=7) as ‘name7’)
From table.1;

Answer (score 0):

You could try to list all values in a nested select listing integers from a to your value, e.g. 100, like that:

```
select count table1.id from table1 one where table1.code in (
     select rownum from all_objects where rownum < 100
);
```

or if you don't want to start at "1":

```
select count table1.id from table1 one where table1.code in (
    select rownum n from dual connect by level 10 where n>3
);
```